# How many integer points does my favorite ellipse goes through?

Tags: diophantine-equations

What value on P gives an ellipse with 768 lattice Points? x^2 + 3y^2 = P
P= 4*7*13*19*31*37*43 gives 384 lattice points

Comment: Using arithmetic in Eulerian integers it is straightforward to determine the number of solutions in terms of the prime decomposition of $P$. Hence this is not a research level question. Please read http://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic

Comment: Just multiply by one more prime that is $1\pmod 3$; for example $61$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, using $P' = P \cdot q$ where $q$ is any of $49,61,67,73,79,97$.

Comment: 49 and 55 are not primes

Comment: Do they have to be? I just coded a program in Mathematica, and these values seem to work... 55?

Comment: The 1/7-ellipse exsists. Can I find an 1/143-elips or an 1/429-ellipse

Comment: The Shippensburg University Problemsolving Group says in Mathematics Magazine vol.60, no4p245 that 1/143 and 1/429 gives ellipses as 1/7 does. Is This true?